# python/pandas Pull month just once from dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I have a dataframe that looks like this below:

```
df = 

            Portfolio Value  Reference Values
Date                                         
2017-12-08     1.116178e+06      1.131236e+06
2017-12-15     1.117073e+06      1.139133e+06
2017-12-22     1.132547e+06      1.148579e+06
2017-12-29     1.138442e+06      1.147916e+06
2018-01-05     1.164225e+06      1.176083e+06
2018-01-12     1.187353e+06      1.196030e+06
2018-01-19     1.189111e+06      1.201825e+06
2018-01-26     1.206821e+06      1.225157e+06
2018-02-02     1.158117e+06      1.176250e+06
2018-02-09     1.100856e+06      1.115643e+06
2018-02-16     1.147286e+06      1.161896e+06
2018-02-23     1.150850e+06      1.169671e+06
2018-03-02     1.131918e+06      1.142618e+06
2018-03-09     1.176213e+06      1.183319e+06
2018-03-16     1.169246e+06      1.168313e+06
2018-03-23     1.115895e+06      1.107276e+06
2018-03-30     1.142702e+06      1.129814e+06
2018-04-06     1.131622e+06      1.115807e+06
2018-04-13     1.155948e+06      1.140644e+06
2018-04-20     1.167440e+06      1.151066e+06
2018-04-27     1.161850e+06      1.147982e+06
2018-05-04     1.156383e+06      1.146540e+06
2018-05-11     1.188791e+06      1.175786e+06
```

I would like to get a list of months from the dataframe with weekly data in it but not repeating the same month. For example, right now in the beginning of the dataframe month 12 shows up four times, however in my list I would like for it to only show up once. This statement is valid for all months.

I would like the end result to look something like this:

```
monthList = [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

my actual dataframes would have many years with varying start months and end months so I was hoping the end result would look something like this:

```
monthList = [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #etc...
```

the `monthList` should start on the month in the dataframe and end on the month the dataframe ends on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `unique`

```
df.index.month.unique().tolist()
Out[99]: [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For multiple years

```
pd.Series(df.index.month).groupby(df.index.year).unique()
Out[105]: 
Date
2017               [12]
2018    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: that's really helpful, I was also trying

Comment: @Wen thank you for all your help. I was wondering, for multiple years, how I would be able to call the list `[12]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` to use in a function? Or better yet, is there a way to merge all the months into one large list?

Comment: @lee.edward01 `np.concatenate(pd.Series(df.index.month).groupby(df.index.year).unique().values).tolist()`

Comment: This is off topic so I apologise, but what are you running python in that produces the `Out[##]` ? I've seen that a ton here, but can't figure out what/why that shows up? Is that a different interpreter than the standard IDLE?

Comment: @BruceWayne you can check pycharm